# Sustituir datos faltantes de una columna con los datos de una nueva base de datos

Tags: rstudio

Tengo dos bases de datos iguales, por cada ID tengo una columna con LATERALIDAD (derecha o izquierda) y otra con un volumen.ejemplo:

ID   LATERALIDAD    VOLUMEN
1     right           83
1     left            50
2     right           36
2     left            52
3     right           65
3     left            29

en una base de datos me faltan valores de VOLUMEN que lo tengo en la segunda base de datos. Como puedo sustituirlos?
Con MERGE me cuadruplica los ID y no sé por qué...
Gracias de antemano

Comment: Te recomiendo que hagas el [tour] y leas [ask] y [example] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida

Answer (score 0):

Para remplazar los valores faltantes en la primer base de datos con los valores de la segunda, podes usar:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!A:C,3,FALSE),C2)
```

Esta formula busca los ID en la segunda sheet y devuelve el volume value si existe, o sino devuelve el volumen value de la primer sheet. Podes copiar y pegar esta formula en la columna volumen de la primer sheet por cada id.

Para evitar el inconveniente de los IDs cuadruplicados cuando usas MERGE, asegurate que los IDs sean únicos en ambos sheets. Si hay valores duplicados podes usar esta formula para removerlos:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A:A,MATCH(0,COUNTIF(A$1:A1,A:A),0)),A2)
```

Esta formula devuelve la primer ocurrencia de cada ID en la lista.